# Possible to save OmniOS packages?

Tags: solaris, omnios

I install the following non standard packages

```
pkg set-publisher -g http://pkg.omniti.com/omniti-ms/ ms.omniti.com
pkg install omniti/system/mbuffer
pkg install omniti/system/storage/smartmontools
pkg install archiver/gnu-tar
```

and as OmniTI have given OmniOS to the community, their repos might go away one day.

**Question**

Is there a way to download the packages, so I can install them on other machine if/when the repo is gone?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the your own local repository:

   ```
   # pkgrepo create /export/repo_your_name
   ```
2. Copy the Repository

   ```
   # pkgrecv -s http://pkg.omniti.com/omniti-ms/ -d /export/repo_your_name '*'
   ```

After the repository is copied, wait a few minutes  until you get your prompt back. The process still does some finish work after you see the *Completed* line.